# One off request for location?

Tags: iphone, ios4, cllocationmanager

Is there a way using CLLocationManager to ask for a one off location, the equivalent of saying "when I press this button, tell me where I am" or is it just a case of calling

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
// and implementing: locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

It can take some time to get a location which is why the `CLLocationManager` uses a delegate. You have to call `stopUpdating` location in the callback `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`.